# Iterate through multiple files in multiple folders and load all into a DF if name matches a condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to loop through many files in many folders in a datalake.  I'm two ideas, as seen below.

```
// first attempt
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
val myDFCsv = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .option("header","false")
   .load("mnt/rawdata/corp/CW*.gz")
   .withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())

myDFCsv.count()

// second attempt
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

val myDFCsv = spark.read
   .option("sep", "|")
   .option("inferSchema", "true")
   .option("header", "false")
   .csv("mnt/rawdata/corp/CW*.gz")
   .withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())

myDFCsv.count()
```

In both cases, I'm getting this error.

```
myDFCsv:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 3 more fields]
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
myDFCsv: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 3 more fields]
res11: Long = 97
```

This must be very close to working, but something seems to be off, and I can't tell what it is.  Can someone point out the issue and let me know what's wrong here?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here, this is not an error, the output is telling you that you:

1. have a dataframe called : myDFCsv with 5 fields
2. did an import of org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
3. have a dataframe called myDFCsv with 5 fields
4. counted the number of lines in the dataframe and you got 97 as a result

You can start using the dataframe and seeing its content using the following command : `myDFCsv.show(false)`

you can also check the schema of your dataframe using the following operation : 
`myDFCsv.printSchema()`

I hope it helps,

Comment: Oh, I see.  Ok, I am new to this.  Thanks for confirming.  One more question...is this a best practice?  Or, is there a better way to do this kind of thing, perhaps.  I read some things about Sqoop.  That seems like a viable alternative.   I tested a coupe Sqoop ideas, but didn't get anything working.  The challenge is to merge hundreds of files together, add in the file name relative to each, and load it all into a SQL Server table.  There are several moving parts here.